# Convert a html string to csv format using javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, html-table

I have an issue in trying to convert a html string into csv format, so that I can then create a new csv blob object and open that from a webpage in IE & Edge.

I've found a function to convert a table object to csv format, but unfortunately I need to pass this a string, not the object.

Here is the table object to csv method:

```
function (table) {

                var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

                return slice.call( table.rows ).map(function ( row ) {
                    return slice.call( row.cells ).map(function ( cell ) {
                        return '"t"'.replace( "t", cell.textContent );
                    }).join( "," );
                }).join( "\r\n" );

            }
```

The problem is the what I wish to display in the csv needs to be formatted before display. So if I just take the table object as it appears on the page, the csv will have far more data in it than is required.
When the export button is clicked, I have a method that formats the table and returns a html string of the table to be displayed as csv.
But I don't know how to convert that string to csv format and cant find an example of this anywhere.

**> Edit 1**

Html string that is rendered as csv in Chrome/Firefox

```
<table id='excel_tbl'><tr><td>Name</td><td>Time allowed</td><td>Best score</td><td>Attempts</td></tr><tr><td>
                                    <a class="ng-binding" id="assess_inst_fdd4ddec-9985-4def-9148-b5cd56ee77e6_875650db-4934-40dc-9e30-81c57c3472de" href="#" ng-click="itShowStudent(oPerson.PersonKey, oPerson.RefName)">Michelle27, Michelle27</a>
                                </td><td>
                                    <div class="ng-hide" aria-hidden="true" ng-show="oPerson.MaxMins >= 0.0">
                                        <it-time class="it-time ng-isolate-scope" seconds="-60" precise="true"><div class="time-info-text"><!-- ngIf: seconds < 60 && bPrecise --><div class="ng-scope" ng-if="seconds < 60 &amp;&amp; bPrecise"><span class="large ng-binding">0</span><!-- ngIf: itGetSeconds(seconds) == 1 --><!-- ngIf: itGetSeconds(seconds) != 1 --><span class="small ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="itGetSeconds(seconds) != 1">secs</span><!-- end ngIf: itGetSeconds(seconds) != 1 --></div><!-- end ngIf: seconds < 60 && bPrecise --><!-- ngIf: seconds == 0 && !bPrecise && bUseNone --><!-- ngIf: seconds == 0 && !bPrecise && !bUseNone --><!-- ngIf: seconds > 0 && seconds < 60 && !bPrecise --><!-- ngIf: seconds >= 60 --></div></it-time>
                                    </div>
                                </td><td>
                                    <div class="ng-binding" aria-hidden="false" ng-show="oPerson.BestScore >= 0.0">
                                        33%
                                    </div>
                                </td><td>
                                    <div class="ng-binding" aria-hidden="false" ng-show="oPerson.Attempts > 0">
                                        1
                                    </div>
                                </td></tr><tr><td>
                                    <a class="ng-binding" id="assess_inst_f588c82b-7eef-422c-8125-e8d8118ed549_875650db-4934-40dc-9e30-81c57c3472de" href="#" ng-click="itShowStudent(oPerson.PersonKey, oPerson.RefName)">Michelle33@outlook.com, Michelle33@outlook.com</a>
                                </td><td>
                                    <div class="ng-hide" aria-hidden="true" ng-show="oPerson.MaxMins >= 0.0">
                                        <it-time class="it-time ng-isolate-scope" seconds="-60" precise="true"><div class="time-info-text"><!-- ngIf: seconds < 60 && bPrecise --><div class="ng-scope" ng-if="seconds < 60 &amp;&amp; bPrecise"><span class="large ng-binding">0</span><!-- ngIf: itGetSeconds(seconds) == 1 --><!-- ngIf: itGetSeconds(seconds) != 1 --><span class="small ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="itGetSeconds(seconds) != 1">secs</span><!-- end ngIf: itGetSeconds(seconds) != 1 --></div><!-- end ngIf: seconds < 60 && bPrecise --><!-- ngIf: seconds == 0 && !bPrecise && bUseNone --><!-- ngIf: seconds == 0 && !bPrecise && !bUseNone --><!-- ngIf: seconds > 0 && seconds < 60 && !bPrecise --><!-- ngIf: seconds >= 60 --></div></it-time>
                                    </div>
                                </td><td>
                                    <div class="ng-binding" aria-hidden="false" ng-show="oPerson.BestScore >= 0.0">
                                        100%
                                    </div>
                                </td><td>
                                    <div class="ng-binding" aria-hidden="false" ng-show="oPerson.Attempts > 0">
                                        18
                                    </div>
                                </td></tr><tr><td>
                                    <a class="ng-binding" id="assess_inst_a820d6e4-1e68-4265-9580-f053cf09cb11_875650db-4934-40dc-9e30-81c57c3472de" href="#" ng-click="itShowStudent(oPerson.PersonKey, oPerson.RefName)">Michelle35, Michelle35</a>
                                </td><td>
                                    <div class="ng-hide" aria-hidden="true" ng-show="oPerson.MaxMins >= 0.0">
                                        <it-time class="it-time ng-isolate-scope" seconds="-60" precise="true"><div class="time-info-text"><!-- ngIf: seconds < 60 && bPrecise --><div class="ng-scope" ng-if="seconds < 60 &amp;&amp; bPrecise"><span class="large ng-binding">0</span><!-- ngIf: itGetSeconds(seconds) == 1 --><!-- ngIf: itGetSeconds(seconds) != 1 --><span class="small ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="itGetSeconds(seconds) != 1">secs</span><!-- end ngIf: itGetSeconds(seconds) != 1 --></div><!-- end ngIf: seconds < 60 && bPrecise --><!-- ngIf: seconds == 0 && !bPrecise && bUseNone --><!-- ngIf: seconds == 0 && !bPrecise && !bUseNone --><!-- ngIf: seconds > 0 && seconds < 60 && !bPrecise --><!-- ngIf: seconds >= 60 --></div></it-time>
                                    </div>
                                </td><td>
                                    <div class="ng-binding" aria-hidden="false" ng-show="oPerson.BestScore >= 0.0">
                                        100%
                                    </div>
                                </td><td>
                                    <div class="ng-binding" aria-hidden="false" ng-show="oPerson.Attempts > 0">
                                        4
                                    </div>
                                </td></tr></table>
```

The above string is passed to

```
document.open("txt/html", "replace");
                    iframe.document.write(sHTML);
```

when using Chrome/Firefox and rendered as follows:

[image]

I cannot get document.open to work with Edge, so Im using the Blob approach.

```
var csv = $scope.tbl2csv(oTable[0]);
                    // Create a CSV Blob
                    var blob = new Blob( [ csv ], { type: "text/csv"} );


                    if ( navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ) {
                        // Works for Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge
                        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, "Assessment.csv" );
                    }
```

This works in Edge, the export of the table to csv opening in excel as required, the problem is that the table object converted to csv format is not the same as the html string that is rendered by Chrome/Firefox.
So my requirement is to find a way to convert that string to csv format.

Comment: The only correct way to treat HTML is to send it to an HTML parser. You know what to do from there.

Comment: And no, this is not a CSV generator, even though it generates valid CSV most of the time.

Comment: @JanDvorak thks for the response. Unfortunately I haven't a clue what to do get my html string (which is the table that I want to display as a csv) into csv format. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of input and the expected output?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question to show you the input html string and an example of the outputted csv

Answer (score 0):

Well I've come up with a solution (not perfect by any means), that works.
I've added the table I need to convert to csv, to the html page, with a display of 'none'. That way, its available to the tbl2csv method when required. This method take a basic html table object as input, and converts to csv format.

```
function (table) {

            var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

            return slice.call(table.rows).map(function (row) {
                    return slice.call( row.cells ).map(function ( cell ) {
                        return '"t"'.replace( "t", cell.textContent );
                    }).join( "," );
                }).join( "\r\n" );

            }
```

Here's the client-side call to the above method:

```
if (edge >= 0) {

                    var oTbl = document.querySelector("#edge_excel_tbl");
                    var csv = $scope.tbl2csv(oTbl);
                    // Create a CSV Blob
                    var blob = new Blob( [ csv ], { type: "text/csv"} );

                    // Determine which approach to take for the download
                    if ( navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ) {
                        // Works for Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge

                        //Get Assessment File Name
                        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, "Assessment.csv" );
                    }
```

Here's the html I added to the page itself.

```
                    <table id="edge_excel_tbl" style="display: none;" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <!--<td></td>-->
                                <td>{{itGetString("instructor", "People_Name", "Name")}}</td>
                                <td>{{itGetString("instructor", "Assess_TimeAvail", "Time allowed")}}</td>
                                <td>{{itGetString("instructor", "Assess_BestScore", "Best score")}}</td>
                                <td>{{itGetString("instructor", "Assess_Attempts", "Attempts")}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="oPerson in itGetGroupAssessmentDetails().Done">
                                <td>{{oPerson.RefName}}</td>
                                <td><it-time class="it-time" precise="true" seconds="{{oPerson.MaxMins * 60.0}}"></it-time></td>
                                <td>{{itGetRoundedScore(oPerson.BestScore)}}%</td>
                                <td>{{oPerson.Attempts}}</td>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <!-- End of Edge Table for Excel Export -->
```

Its not the most flexible approach, but it works in Edge in terms of delivering an csv doc (opened in excel in this case) that matches that for all other browsers.
The other alternative was to write a tbl2csv method that took a html string as input and formatted that to csv. That would have been much more complex and time-consuming.